# Linux -grep command

Tags: linux, grep, text-files

Evening, Im busy learning Linux in University and one of the projects due is a text document explaining some Linux commands aswell as section that included text file handling and alterations via Terminal.

Iv done operations such as Replace but im stuck on the next operation. The question asks us to replace the word "bv" with "example" in the first 10 lines of the textfile only. The command should be used in one way that terminal should 1. Give no feedback aswell as in a way that 2. Shows the result after the change on screen.

What I am struggling to find is the command to limit the changes to 10 lines only aswell as the command to show no feedback and show all changes aswell, if anyone can point me in the right direction or what operator I would use to achieve this Ill gladly do research and read up after.

Thanks.

Comment: You can post your partially working solution, so that folks don't get an impression that you are trying to get us to do your homework. See also: [ask]

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you use `sed` for replacing, you can supply ranges to your command using

```
sed '1,10s/a/b/'
```

Answer (score 0):

Came up with this and it seems to be working:

```
$ sed –n ‘1,10s/bv/example/gp’ /home/soprono/Documents/data
```